# Perform a Standard Deviation on the values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.7, numpy

I'm using Numpy and Python2.7, and I'm writing a function that counts the amount of times a color appears per column of pixels as I read-in an image (Using PIL):

```
for i in range(wbmp.size[0]):
    bcount = 0
    for j in range(wbmp.size[1]):
        if wbmp.getpixel((i,j)) == 1:
            bcount = bcount + 1
    bdict[i] = bcount
```

The dictionary returns as `{Column#: # of times color appears}`, and I'd like to be able to perform a standard deviation on all of the values in the dictionary.  Would I need to put them all into a list first?  Or is there away to just pull it from the dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list of all values in the dictionary can be obtained with `bdict.values()`, so you could use this:

```
std = np.std(bdict.values())
```

A faster way to do this would use more numpy:

```
img = np.array(img)
colour_mask = img == 1  # or whichever colour you want
per_col_count = colour_mask.sum(axis=0)
std = np.std(per_col_count)
```

`colour_mask` is a boolean mask, and summing it along axis 0 adds up all `True` values for every column. This is bound to be much faster, and the difference will increase with the size of the image.

Comment: nice, the mask and sum idea is much better than my using `np.histogram` :)

Comment: @askewchan Thanks! I actually came up with it after reading your histogram code

Comment: That's so much faster!  Something like 20 lines of code shorter haha.  Is there a way to remove certain columns using this?

Comment: Do you mean ignore them in the std calculation? If so, create a mask with `True` values in the columns you need, and use `np.std(per_col_count[mask])`

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionary already has the list you want,

```
bdict.values()
```

So you can call `std` on this:

```
np.std(bdict.values())
```

But I would recommend converting your image into a numpy array immediately, and doing a histogram along one axis, instead of using your version of counting.

```
from PIL import Image
i = Image.open('imfile.png')
a = np.array(i)
c = 1   # or whatever color you want
b = 256 # bit depth of image, so histogram bins are 1 color / bin

hists = np.array([ np.histogram(row, bins=b)[0] for row in a ])
s = hists[:,c].std()
```